# My mail function return success and the mail is not received when there is french accent in the message

Tags: php, ajax, email, accent-sensitive

So I've got a script that send a mail from a form on my web page. The user simply put his mail address, the message and his name.

First I send the mail to my contact address. (This is working fine) And after that I send a mail to the user's mail address. (This in not working)

And the last mail function return a success but the user doesn't got a mail.

I tried to log everything and I can't figure out why the mail is probably sent but not received.

The mail is not sending when I have a french accent in the body like "répondons" but it works when it's just "repondons". I don't understand why, but It would be better with accent

```php
<?php
    // site owner
    $site_name = 'just-request.fr';
    $sender_domain = 'contact@just-request.fr';
    $to = 'contact@just-request.fr';


    // contact form fields
    $name = trim( $_POST['name'] );
    $email = trim( $_POST['email'] );
    $subject = trim( $_POST['subject'] );
    $message = trim( $_POST['message'] );


    // check for error
    $error = false;

    if ( $name === "" ) { $error = true; }

    if ( $email === "" ) { $error = true; }

    if ( $subject === "" ) { $error = true; }

    if ( $message === "" ) { $error = true; }


    // if no error, then send mail
    if ( $error == false )
    {
        $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nMessage: $message";

        $headers = "From: " . $site_name . ' <' . $sender_domain . '> ' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: " . $name . ' <' . $email . '> ' . "\r\n";

        $mail_result = mail( $to, utf8_decode($subject), utf8_decode($body), $headers );

        if ( $mail_result == true )
        {
            $body = "Bonjour,\n\n";
            $body .= "Merci de votre mail, nous le prenons en compte et vous repondrons des que possible.\n\n";
            $body .= "Cordialement,\n";
            $body .= "L'equipe Request. ";

            $subject = "Réponse automatique";

            $new_mail_result = mail( $email, utf8_decode($subject), utf8_decode($body), $headers );

            if ( $new_mail_result == true )
            {
                echo 'success';
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'unsuccess';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'unsuccess';
        }
    }

    else
    {
        echo 'error';
    }
```

Comment: Why not `utf8_encode` ?

Comment: It's not working either. When I've got an accent in $body, it's just not working. I don't receive the mail

Comment: Which service is the email that's not working? Gmail, Yahoo?

Comment: The sender is host on Hostinger, the first received mail is on Hostinger too and the one that's not working I've to send it to an Hotmail and Gmail account

Comment: Have you checked the spam folder?

Comment: Yeah.. And like I said I can receive the mail when there is no accent

Comment: Try to add the $headers `$headers .= 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8'."\r\n";`

Comment: Ok so now I receive the mail but the accent is replaced by �

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [mb_send_mail()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-send-mail.php) instead of [mail()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).
Set [mb_language()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-language.php) to `German/de` ([ISO-8859-15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15)) or `English/en` ([ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)).
Both [ISO-8859-15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15) and [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) include french extra letters.
[ISO-8859-15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15) is [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) after [Euro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euro) upgrade.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-send-mail.php

> Sends email. Headers and messages are converted and encoded according to the [mb_language()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-language.php) setting. It's a wrapper function for [mail()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php), so see also [mail()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) for details.

---

Comment: I miss [mb_language()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-language.php) option for [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) with [quoted-printable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) encoding.
It would be nice for most (european) "almost [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)" language specific alphabets.

Comment: Thanks it worked!